# Every function executes on Arduino reset

Tags: arduino-uno

I'm trying to control my home television through android mobile. I took the IR NEC code from the remote through an RF receiver. After that I interfaced Arduino with a WiFi module and IR transmitter. This lets me control my television via WiFi. But the thing is, whenever I reset the Arduino board, all the functions are occurring automatically: power on, channel increase and decrease, volume increase and decrease, and power off. After that, though, I can control it through android mobile and everything will work as intended. But this repeats again when I reset Arduino board. What could be causing this?

I'm attaching the code here:

```
#include<IRremote.h>
IRsend ir;

 char serialA;


void setup() 
{
  pinMode(3, OUTPUT);

  Serial.begin(115200); //baud rate - make sure it matches that of the module you got:
  Serial.println("AT");
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println("AT+CIPMUX=1\r\n");
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println("AT+CIPSERVER=1,80\r\n");
  delay(1000);
}

void loop() 
{
 if (Serial.available()>0 )
  {
   serialA = Serial.read();
   IRREMOTE();
  }
}
void IRREMOTE()
{
  switch (serialA)
    {

        case 'A':         //Power
        ir.sendNEC(0x2FD48B7,32);
        delay(500);
        break;

        case 'B':         // AV/TV
        ir.sendNEC(0x2FD28D7,32);
        delay(500);
        break;

        case 'C':         // Mute
        ir.sendNEC(0x2FD08F7,32);
        delay(500);
        break;

        case 'D':      // CH+
        ir.sendNEC(0x2FDD827,32);
        delay(500);
        break;


         case 'E':    // CH-

         ir.sendNEC(0x2FDF807,32);
         delay(500);
         break;

         case 'F':    // Vol+

         ir.sendNEC(0x2FD58A7,32);
         delay(500);
         break;

          case 'G':    // Vol-

         ir.sendNEC(0x2FD7887,32);
         delay(500);
         break;

         case 'H':
         //  Menu
         ir.sendNEC(0x2FD30CF,32);
         delay(500);
         break;

         case 'I':     
         //  Alt
          ir.sendNEC(0x2FD708F,32);
          delay(500);
          break;

         case 'J':
         // Scan
         ir.sendNEC(0x2FDDA25,32);
         delay(500);
         break;
      }  
}
```

and

```
#include<IRremote.h>
IRsend ir;

char serialA;

void setup() 
{
  pinMode(3, OUTPUT);

  Serial.begin(115200); //baud rate - make sure it matches that of the module you got:
  Serial.println("AT");
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println("AT+CIPMUX=1\r\n");
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println("AT+CIPSERVER=1,80\r\n");
  delay(1000);
}

void loop() 
{
 if (Serial.available()>0 )
  {
   serialA = Serial.read();
   IRREMOTE();
  }
}
void IRREMOTE()
{
       if(serialA == '$')     //Power
       {
        ir.sendNEC(0x2FD48B7,32);
       }

       else if(serialA == 'b')    // AV/TV
       {
        ir.sendNEC(0x2FD28D7,32);
       }

       else if(serialA == 'c')    // Mute
       {
        ir.sendNEC(0x2FD08F7,32);
       }

       else if(serialA == 'd')    // CH+
       {       
        ir.sendNEC(0x2FDD827,32);
       }

       else if(serialA == 'e')    // CH-
       {         
         ir.sendNEC(0x2FDF807,32);
       }

       else if(serialA == 'f')    // Vol+
       {
         ir.sendNEC(0x2FD58A7,32);
       }

       else if(serialA == 'g')    // Vol-
       { 
         ir.sendNEC(0x2FD7887,32);
       }

       else if(serialA == 'h')    //  Menu
       {
         ir.sendNEC(0x2FD30CF,32);
       }

       else if(serialA == 'i')    //  Alt
       {
          ir.sendNEC(0x2FD708F,32);
       }

       else if(serialA == 'j')    // Scan
       {
         ir.sendNEC(0x2FDDA25,32);
       }  
}
```

Comment: Hello friend,    I tried with clearing input buffer also.  But still i'm facing the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Hayes commands being send to a serial device usually generate a response. For example, when you send that AT command, device listening for that command will respond "OK". Also, in certain scenarios, what you write to the device/serial line may get echoed back to your input handler (Serial.read())

so, in order to fix your issue, you should clear the input buffer completely after you send the last AT command.